# How to publish fork of an ESLint plugin

Tags: npm, eslint

ESLint plugins follow a naming convention: `eslint-plugin-horses`

I'd like to publish a fork of an under-maintained ESLint plugin, but, if I change package name to `eslint-plugin-DEVIN-horses` then other ESLint plugins/configs referencing `horses` will need to now reference `DEVIN-horses`.

A core issue is that our company proxy does not allow packages to be installed directly from GitHub, otherwise, I'd be using this `package.json` dependency syntax:

```json
"eslint-plugin-horses": "devinrhode2/eslint-plugin-horses#no-horse-shoes"
```

Comment: Publishing a fork with package name `@devinrhode2/eslint-plugin-node`, I got this error: "ESLint v7.32.0. ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-node". https://cln.sh/cKfH3T7tD845T7st3DXd

Comment: Note: I even used patch-package to correct the package name: `code node_modules/@devinrhode2/eslint-plugin-node/package.json` and `npx patch-package --exclude 'nothing' @devinrhode2/eslint-plugin-node`

Comment: ESLint doesn't search through `node_modules` looking for the right `name`, it basically does e.g. `require("eslint-plugin-" + name);`. If you want to use your own fork and can't control what `eslint-plugin-node` resolves to, you'll have to change the references to rules etc. too.